# Python Acme V2 - Reuse Order/Challenge

Tags: python, ssl, lets-encrypt, acme

I'm using python-acme to write a small script that does takes in a domain and does one of two things:

- Using the DNS01 challenge, if the challenge doesn't pass, return the DNS entry that needs to be added to the domain.
- Using the DNS01 challenge, if the challenge passes, return the certificate information.

I'm running into issues however, and the documentation is just terrible :P I'm trying to find a way to "reuse" the order/challenge. Basically, any time I run the script so far, the validation token for the DNS entry changes.

```
    print("Validating Challenge...")
    response, validation = challenge.response_and_validation(client_acme.net.key)
    print("response %s" % response.to_partial_json())
    print("validation %s" % validation)
    print("-> Validation Domain: %s" % challenge.chall.validation_domain_name(domain))
    print("-> Validation Value: %s" % challenge.chall.validation(client_acme.net.key))
    # TODO - We are here, gotta actually get info on the DNS challange and attempt to validate.
    print("Validation Completed!")
```

Things I've tried:

- Register the account with the same RSA key. Runs into validation errors when registering.
- Running `new_order` with the same CSR. Still returns a different key.

---

**Full Code (In It's Prototype Glory)**

```
import json
import josepy as jose
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key
from acme import client
from acme import messages
from acme import challenges
from acme import crypto_util
import OpenSSL

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

"""
Generates an SSL certificate through Let's Encrypt provided a domain. If the 
domain requires a DNS challenge to be passed, that information is passed back
to the user. Otherwise, the SSL certificate is generated and returned back to
the user.

Documentation for generating SSL via this method:
http://www.gilesthomas.com/2018/11/python-code-to-generate-lets-encrypt-certificates/

ACME Documentation:
https://kite.com/python/docs/acme.client.ClientV2.new_order
"""

print('Loading function')

DEBUG = True

DIRECTORY_URL = 'https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory'
KEY_SIZE = 2048
CERT_PKEY_BITS = 2048
USER_AGENT = 'python-acme-example'
EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'REDACTED'

S3_BUCKET = 'REDACTED'
S3_KEY = 'REDACTED'
S3_SECRET = 'REDACTED'


# TODO - Load These From Event
PASSWORD = "swordfish" 
SALT = "yourAppName"  


def new_csr_comp(domain_name, pkey_pem=None):
    """Create certificate signing request."""
    if pkey_pem is None:
        # Create private key.
        pkey = OpenSSL.crypto.PKey()
        pkey.generate_key(OpenSSL.crypto.TYPE_RSA, CERT_PKEY_BITS)
        pkey_pem = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
                                                  pkey)
    csr_pem = crypto_util.make_csr(pkey_pem, [domain_name])
    return pkey_pem, csr_pem

def save_key(pk, filename):
    pem = pk.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
    )
    return pem

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Formatting Domain...")
    domain = event['domain']
    domain = domain.lower()
    print("Formatted! Domain is: %s" % domain)

    print("Generating User Key...")
    conn = S3Connection(S3_KEY, S3_SECRET)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(S3_BUCKET)
    key_name = "%s.key" % domain
    existing_account = False
    print("-> Looking For Existing Key.")
    rsa_key = bucket.get_key(key_name)
    if rsa_key is None or DEBUG:
        print("-> Key Not Found. Creating New One.")
        rsa_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
                public_exponent=65537,
                key_size=KEY_SIZE,
                backend=default_backend()
            )
        pem = save_key(rsa_key, key_name)
        print(key_name)
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = key_name
        k.set_contents_from_string(pem)
    else:
        print("-> Key File Found.")
        existing_account = True
        rsa_key = rsa_key.get_contents_as_string()
        rsa_key = load_pem_private_key(rsa_key, password=None, backend=default_backend())
        print(rsa_key)
        print("-> Converted File To Usable Format.")
    acc_key = jose.JWKRSA(
            key=rsa_key
        )
    print("Generated!")

    print("Registering With Let's Encrypt...")
    print("-> Connecting to Let's Encrypt on {}".format(DIRECTORY_URL))
    net = client.ClientNetwork(acc_key, user_agent=USER_AGENT)
    directory = messages.Directory.from_json(net.get(DIRECTORY_URL).json())
    client_acme = client.ClientV2(directory, net=net)
    print("-> Registering")
    email = (EMAIL_ADDRESS)
    regr = None 
    # TODO - Use Existing Account
    # if existing_account:
    #     regr = messages.NewRegistration(key=acc_key.public_key(), only_return_existing=True)
    # else:
    account_created = messages.NewRegistration.from_data(email=email, terms_of_service_agreed=True)
    regr = client_acme.new_account(account_created)
    print("Registered!")

    print("Creating CSR...")
    temp_pkey_pem, temp_csr_pem = new_csr_comp(domain)
    key_name = "%s.pkey_pem" % domain
    pkey_pem = bucket.get_key(key_name)
    if pkey_pem is None:
        print("-> Creating New PKEY")
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = key_name
        k.set_contents_from_string(temp_pkey_pem)
        pkey_pem = temp_pkey_pem
    else:
        print("-> Using Existing PKEY")
        pkey_pem = pkey_pem.get_contents_as_string()
    key_name = "%s.csr_pem" % domain
    csr_pem = bucket.get_key(key_name)
    if csr_pem is None:
        print("-> Creating New CSR")
        k = Key(bucket)
        k.key = key_name
        k.set_contents_from_string(temp_csr_pem)
        csr_pem = temp_csr_pem
    else:
        print("-> Using Existing CSR")
        csr_pem = csr_pem.get_contents_as_string()
    print("Created!")

    print("Requesting Challenges...")
    orderr = client_acme.new_order(csr_pem)
    print("Requested!")

    print("Selecting DNS Challenge...")
    challenge = None
    authz_list = orderr.authorizations
    for authz in authz_list:
        for i in authz.body.challenges:
            if isinstance(i.chall, challenges.DNS01):
                challenge = i
            else:
                print("-> Other challenge found: %s" % i.chall)
    if challenge is None:
        raise Exception("Could not find a DNS challenge!")
    print("Selected!")

    print("Validating Challenge...")
    response, validation = challenge.response_and_validation(client_acme.net.key)
    print("response %s" % response.to_partial_json())
    print("validation %s" % validation)
    print("-> Validation Domain: %s" % challenge.chall.validation_domain_name(domain))
    print("-> Validation Value: %s" % challenge.chall.validation(client_acme.net.key))
    # TODO - We are here, gotta actually get info on the DNS challange and attempt to validate.
    print("Validation Completed!")

    print("Starting Challenge...")
    client_acme.answer_challenge(challenge, response)
    finalized_orderr = client_acme.poll_and_finalize(orderr)
    fullchain_pem = finalized_orderr.fullchain_pem
    print("-> PEM: %s" % fullchain_pem)
    print("Challenge Completed!")

    # TODO - We need to return the DNS challenge if it hasn't been completed yet.

    return "done"
    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

Answer (score 1):

Bryant

```
print("Starting Challenge...")
client_acme.answer_challenge(challenge, response)
finalized_orderr = client_acme.poll_and_finalize(orderr)
fullchain_pem = finalized_orderr.fullchain_pem
print("-> PEM: %s" % fullchain_pem)
print("Challenge Completed!")`enter code here`
```

Each time you run this code block, it will send a challenge to LetsEncrypt Server. If this challenge success it will return your certs and everything ok, but if challenge invalid LetsEncrypt Server will change your Key Authoriztion and TXT value.

Hope, its help.

Comment: Got it, so as long as I don't run `answer_challenge` the TXT record will remain unchanged? Is running `new_order` going to keep the same TXT record?

Comment: I checked, and that doesn't seem to fix the issue. I added a break to skip answering the challenge but new TXT values are still displayed. Sanity check; `print("-> Validation Value: %s" % challenge.chall.validation(client_acme.net.key))` is returning the TXT value, correct? (So little documentation lol)